# I get strange error while using package" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. "

Tags: java, exception, package, program-entry-point, noclassdeffounderror

I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" while using "package"

1. if I comment "//package com.kevin.corejava; " it would run successfully;
2. Or, I delete the "main" method in "Employee.java", and add a class "Test.java" in folder "E:\Space\java" which imports "Employee.java" (import com.kevin.corejava.*), and reference Employee int its main method, it would still run successfully.

Why the "main" method in Employee could not run by itself when I add the sentence "package com.kevin.corejava" (Employee.java is put in path E:\Space\java\com\kevin\corejava\Employee.java)

```
package com.kevin.corejava;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Employee
{
    public Employee(String n, double s, int year, int month, int day)
    {
        name = n;
        salary = s;
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1,day);
        hireDay = calendar.getTime();
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
    public Date getHireDay()
    {
        return hireDay;
    }
    public void raiseSalary(double byPercent)
    {
        double raise = salary *byPercent/100;
        salary+=raise;
    }

    private String name;
    private double salary;
    private Date hireDay;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("This is main ,I won't say 'Hello World'!");
    }

}
```

Comment: is Employee class public?

Comment: what is the package command?

Comment: Besides just writing package declaration won't make class available if it's not on the classpath.

Comment: to Lucas: Employee is public class;

Comment: to Mysterion: command is "package com.kevin.corejava;"

Comment: to Lucas: Employee.java is on the path E:\Space\java\ **com\kevin\corejava\Employee.java**  @Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you follow the below things :

> 1. "package com.kevin.corejava;" It should be a valid path.
> 2. Your package path must be executed by JDK, and JRE must access its class file. (Make Sure your JDK and JRE paths are right to access this
>      file).
> 3. The class name must be same as the file name as the main method is in your Employee class.
> 4. Your project's Build path is right. If you use Eclipse or other IDE, just right click and configure your build path.